# Subtraction and addition results in calculator are incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a for loop calculator using `HTML` and `Javascript`, I tried everything I know. The problem is the result in subtract is incorrect, same thing as in addition.

Here's the function

```
<script>
    var num1 = 0, num2 = 0, resultt = 1, resultt = 1;
    var init = 0, inc = 0, imput = 0;
    function gen() {
        imput = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
        for(init = 1; init <= imput; init++) {
            document.write("<input type='text' value='" + init + "' id='" + init + "'><br>");
        }

        document.write("<input type='button' value='compute'onclick='computee();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy'></div></br>");
        document.write("<input type='button' value='subtract'onclick='subtractt();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy'></div></br>");
        document.write("<input type='button' value='division'onclick='divisionn();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy'></div></br>");
        document.write("<input type='button' value='multiplication'onclick='multiplicationn();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy'></div></br>");      
    }
```

Here's the other Half

```
    function computee() {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++) {
            resultt = resultt + parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }

        document.getElementById("displayy").innerHTML = resultt;
    }

    function subtractt() {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++) {
            resultt = resultt - parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }

        document.getElementById("displayy").innerHTML = resultt;
    }

    function divisionn() {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++) {
            resultt = resultt % parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy").innerHTML = resultt;
    }

    function multiplicationn() {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++) {
            resultt = resultt * parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy").innerHTML = resultt;
    }

</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="txt1" placeholder="enter number of textboxes" onkeyup="solve();">
        <input type="button" value="generate" onclick="gen()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should tag java-script not java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculator using javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022553/calculator-using-javascript-code)

Comment: "result in Subtract is Incorrect" -- This is a very vague description. Please be specific as to what is the error.

Comment: That's not solve your error, but don't use multiple id="displayy". An id by definition is unique. Inverse quote and double quote when you write html with javascript.

Comment: INPUT: 5

OUTPUT:
1
2
3
4
5

subract: -14
(it Must Be "-13")

addition:16
(It must be "15")

Answer (score 0):

1- your div output have the same ids, and 2- `ParseInt` in multiplication and division must be `parseFloat`

```js
 var num1 = 0, num2 = 0, resultt = 1, resultt = 1;
            var init = 0, inc = 0, imput = 0;
            function gen()
            {
                imput = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                for(init = 1; init <= imput; init++)
                {
                document.write("<input type='text' value='" + init + "' id='" + init + "'><br>");
                }
                document.write("<input type='button' value='compute'onclick='computee();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy1'></div></br>");
                document.write("<input type='button' value='subtract'onclick='subtractt();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy2'></div></br>");
                document.write("<input type='button' value='division'onclick='divisionn();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy3'></div></br>");
                document.write("<input type='button' value='multiplication'onclick='multiplicationn();'><div style='border: 1px solid black;' id='displayy4'></div></br>");      
            }
                function computee()
        {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++)
        {
            resultt = resultt + parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy1").innerHTML = resultt;
        }
        function subtractt()
        {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++)
        {
            resultt = resultt - parseInt(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy2").innerHTML = resultt;
        }
        function divisionn()
        {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++)
        {
            resultt = resultt / parseFloat(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy3").innerHTML = resultt;
        }
        function multiplicationn()
        {
        var imputt = "";
        for(inc = 1; inc <= init - 1; inc++)
        {
            resultt = resultt * parseFloat(document.getElementById(inc).value);
        }
        document.getElementById("displayy4").innerHTML = resultt;
        }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txt1" placeholder="enter number of textboxes">
 <input type="button" value="generate" onclick="gen()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I at least think I've made what you want..

Plase go ahead and take a look at it:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', e => calculateStuff(e.target.value));

function calculateStuff(numb) {
  let addition = 1;
  let subtraction = 1;
  let multiplication = 1;
  let division = 1;
  for(let i = 2; i <= parseInt(numb); i++) {
   addition += i;
    subtraction -= i;
    multiplication *= i;
    division /= i;
  }
  
  console.log('// *********************** //');
  console.log('Addition:', addition);
  console.log('Subtraction:', subtraction);
  console.log('Multiplicaton:', multiplication);
  console.log('Division:', division);
  console.log('// *********************** //');
}
```

```html
Input number: <input type="number" id="input" />
```

I pre-assign 1 to every operation as otherwise I'd be dividing zero by one and so forth... That's why the loop then starts at 2. Otherwise code is self explanatory, at least in my opinion, so if you need some explanations let me know :)